# Remove or hide a specific date in fullcalendar V5

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm trying to remove or hide dates / days from fullcalendar V5
for example I have these dates: **2021-09-10 and 2021-09-12**
what I am trying to do is not to show the dates or events on that day.

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var MyDate = new Date(2021, 9, 10);

    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
        locale: 'es',
        headerToolbar: {
            right: "timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek",
            center: "title",
            left: "prev,next"
        },

        // No muestro los fines de semana
        weekends: false,
        hiddenDays: [0, 6],

        // Hora minima y maxima en la que se van a mostrar los eventos, con 30 minutos de separacion
        timeFormat: 'H:mm',
        axisFormat: 'HH:mm',
        slotMinTime: '11:00',
        slotMaxTime: '21:00',

        dayRender: function (cell) {
            MyDate.css("visibility", "hidden");
            cell.css("visibility", "hidden");
        },

       events: [
          {
            url: 'alltwo.php', // use the `url` property
            color: 'red',
          }
        ],

        eventSources: [
            {
                url: 'all.php', // use the `url` property
                color: '#1c97df',    // an option!
                textColor: 'whitesmoke',  // an option!
                eventColor: '#378006',
                // method: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
            }
        ],
    });

    calendar.render();
});
```

The code is the one I am trying to use but it would not be working.

Version FullCalendar 5.9.0

Comment: What have you tried? Where exactly are you stuck? I don't see anything in your code above which attempts to achieve what you've described. If you tried something, you need to show us an explain the problem. P.S. Which version of fullCalendar are you using? (e.g. v5, v4, v3)

Comment: I tried to bring these days from the database and color them red but I couldn't do it either. @ADyson

Comment: @ADyson I have already modified the question with the complete code.

Comment: If that's your complete code then there is no attempt there to do anything like what you have described. When you said you "couldn't" do it, what exactly did you mean? What exactly did you try? It's not clear what the problem is because you haven't shown us any code which does anything useful towards your stated requirement. We'll _help_ you at stackoverflow, but we're not just going to do it all for you, for free. Show a reasonable effort, and/or explain specifically in detail where you're stuck and then we can assist you.

Comment: @ADyson I was able to solve it, I generated the JSON with its values from a database and I brought them to the view through an ajax.

Comment: That's great. Write it as an answer then, if it would be useful to others, and include the relevant code. Then people might upvote it. If it's not, then just delete the question. Don't leave it dangling. Thanks.